# Snackbar does not show the item name , when delete items from list in Flutter

Tags: flutter, list, dart, snackbar

When I delete items from a list, the snackbar does not show the item name, instead it say: "Instance of 'IngredientList' deleted".

Is it because `.showSnackBar` is desprecated?
How to fix that?

```
showSnackbar(context, ingredient, index){
Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
  content:Text('$ingredient deleted'),
  action: SnackBarAction(
    label: 'UNDO'.tr(),
    onPressed: (){
      undoDelete(index,ingredient);
    },
  ),
));
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `desprecated` message shown because you need to use

```dart
  ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(..)
```

And use `ingredient.toString()` to show instance as String. you need to override the toString on your model class

Like

```dart
class ingredient {
  final String name;
  //....
  @override
  String toString() => 'ingredient(name: $name)';
}
```